# How to create properties of an object with the parameters without having to make en equality for each

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I have a constructor, which creates cables with properties. I want to assign the parameters of the constructor to values of properties with the same name.

```
function SimpleCable(X, Y, totalradius, outerradius, innerradius, Type, name) {
  this.Center = [X, Y];
  this.TotalRadius = totalradius;
  this.ConductorOuterRadiusList = outerradius;
  this.ConductorInnerRadiusList = innerradius;
  this.Type = Type;
  this.Name = name;
}
```

Is it possible to directly assign the name and type parameters without having to make an obvious equality?

I was thinking of something like this, however it does not work.

```
function SimpleCable(X, Y, totalradius, outerradius, innerradius, Type, name) {
  this.Center = [X, Y];
  this.TotalRadius = totalradius;
  this.ConductorOuterRadiusList = outerradius;
  this.ConductorInnerRadiusList = innerradius;
  this.type;
  this.name;
}
```

thank you!

Comment: But those are *not* the "same names". JavaScript cares about UPPER versus lower case.

Comment: Regardless of the case issue, JavaScript does not operate this way. The constructor is designed to help us initialize our objects - including the burden of writing a simple assignment statement for member properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to shorten the constructor initialization, then one way to create properties with the same name as the arguments could be approached using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) (but note this is and `ES6` feature, so it is recommended to [check browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) before using it), like this:

```
function SimpleCable(X, Y, totalRadius, outerRadius, innerRadius, type, name)
{
    Object.assign(
      this,
      {center: [X, Y], totalRadius, outerRadius, innerRadius, type, name}
    );
}
```

## Example

```js
function SimpleCable(X, Y, totalRadius, outerRadius, innerRadius, type, name)
{
    Object.assign(
      this,
      {center: [X, Y], totalRadius, outerRadius, innerRadius, type, name}
    );
}

let cable1 = new SimpleCable(1, 2, 4, 5, 4,"type1", "name1");
console.log("cable1 is:", cable1);

let cable2 = new SimpleCable(7, 6, 7, 3, 2, "type2", "name2");
console.log("cable2 is:", cable2);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
class SimpleCable{
    constructor(options){
        Object.keys(options).forEach(name=>{
            this[name]=options[name];
        });
    }
}
new SimpleCable({center:[5,7], totalRadius:3});
```